# Mamba Ransomware

Tags: malware, malware-detection, antimalware

I need to find more information related to Mamba ransomware to reverse it. I am specifically looking out for IOCs in form of SHA values, IPs, URLs etc. Any related information will be very appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This ransomware propagated mostly through spearphish campaigns. The malicious code once downloaded starts its working by encrypting system drives. Then comes a ransom page threatening the victim to delete all the encrypted files until a ransom, mostly in form of bitcoin is paid to the attacker.

I think this is what you are looking for:

https://www.talentcookie.com/2017/08/mamba-ransomware-back/

Comment: Thanks. This looks great. Loved the article.